# Get summarized/sorted data from SQL Server in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

below is my sql table in which I'm saving student attendance

[image: Check this image]

I'm trying to create a summarized attendance report as below:

**Attendance Summary of all students:**

- Number of students present in class I: 1
- Number of students present in class II: 1
- Number of students present in class III: 0

But I don't exactly am finding a right way to do it. below is the sample code I'm trying to use to achieve this:

```
public void GetPresentCount()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) as 'TotalPresent' from stud_att where att='Present' and a_date='"+ systemdate +"'", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    totstuds.InnerText = dr["TotalCount"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    totstuds.InnerText = "0";
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
public void GetAbsentCount()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) as 'TotalPresent' from stud_att where att='Present' and a_date='" + systemdate + "'", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    totstuds.InnerText = dr["TotalCount"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    totstuds.InnerText = "0";
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

But I know this is not the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select class,
       sum(case when att = 'Present' then 1 else 0 end) as attendance
from stud_att
where a_date = ?
group by class
order by class;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder to pass in the date.  Don't munge SQL queries with constant values; pass them in as parameters.